# "Don't break character" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases, definition

I wanted to know the meaning of this  phrase in the music of “be still” from “killers”:

- “ Don't break character

Comment: to be in character: what an actor does when acting. If the actor stops doing that while acting, he is breaking character. This is not easy to look up but still you might have tried to look it up.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I was reading somewhere and it said that it means: be brave, but I’m still in dubious

Comment: " I was reading somewhere and it said that it means: be brave,"  If you read that somewhere, please find the exact quote and edit it into the question.

Comment: I've cut down the question to one question.  It's not good to have several unrelated phrases in one question.

Comment: I wasn’t quite sure about the authenticity of that website so that’s why I didn’t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Break character" is a term used by actors.  It means when an actor on the stage (or in a film etc) stops pretending to be a character and is just the actor.

> The school play was going well until Tim, who was playing Macbeth, broke character and said "I need to go to the toilet".  Unfortunately, most of the audience started laughing.

Breaking character is usually a failure for the actor, but occasionally it is done for comic effect.  And of course if there is a real emergency, actors will break character.

> When her leading man collapsed, she broke character and asked the audience "Is there a doctor in the house?"

In the context of the song, it means "continue to pretend to be who you pretend to be (or else your lover might leave you)". (or something like that)

Comment: Thank you so much